# Opencart result count moderation

Tags: php, opencart

I am making a website in opencart. I modified search query. By default if i search 'apple iphone 6', then result shown by opencart are 'apple iphone 6', 'apple iphone 6 plus',etc (say total 20 result).

But i modified query such a way to match exact text as in search bar.

so 'apple iphone 6' search will produce only one result. But the problem is in bottom search result number are same as in default. still it is showing

Showing 1 to 10 of 20 (2 Pages)

but there is only one result and second page of pagination is blank.

I also modify filter according to our requirement but it has same problem.

So where can i modify result number.

Comment: Have you modified sql query which returns total number of products?which is used for pagination.?

Answer (score 1):

As **Ved Pandya** said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531201/opencart-result-count-moderation#comment51023365_31531201):

> Have you modified sql query which returns total number of products?which is used for pagination.?

Based on what you said, you have successfully modified the function `getProducts` but also you need to modify the function `getTotalProducts` (the one used for pagination)

**N.B:** When ever you see a pagination in any page in OC, search for this line in the corresponding controller:
`$pagination->total = xxx`
and then find where `xxx` is initialized